# Where can we communicate with server-side script? Only in document class or in sub-class

Tags: actionscript-3

Say i need to send some data from AS 3.0 to a server-side script for it to do some actions. Can I do this in a sub-class called some where in a document class or should we always do it in a document class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why wouldn't this work from another class? As long as the code that sends the data gets called, it will work.

Comment: Side note: 6,500 rep in a month. Respect.

Comment: I'm ashamed of my rep now... I want to ask for a new feature on meta where I can hide how long I've been a member for. :( lol

Comment: Hah! Look at mine.. I am in a decent range.. Not too high ;)

Comment: @AscensionSystems I have been here slightly longer than you, and I visit this site everyday, my reputation isn't even half yours, that's true shame :(

Comment: lol I think I got to over 3K rep after the first couple of months of being on here but that was going overkill spending a ton of time on the site pretty much just digging for rep. But over 6K in a month, that's just incredible lol

Comment: ah, but you don't get rep for answering as3 questions ;) try c++ or iphone